# How can I trim a nested list with applying conditions?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a nested list.

```
list_ = [['a','1'], ['b','2'], ['c','3'], ['a','4'], ['d','5'], ['e','6'], ['a','7'], ['b','8'], ['f','9'], ['g', '10']]
```

I want to trim the list by applying condition that decides which sublist should I delete. For example, I'm looking for a list like
(edit: dictionary like {'b':'2', 'c':'3', ... , 'g':'10'} would also do. I will convert it into list later.)

```
list_ = [['b','2'], ['c','3'], ['a','4'], ['d','5'], ['e','6'], ['f','9'], ['g', '10']]
```

what I tried is giving error:

```
for i in range(len(list_)):
    for j in range(len(list_)):
        if list[i][0] == list[j][0] and i != j:
            string = input("the '{:}' has already a value '{:}'. Do you want to replace it with '{:}'?".format(i[0],i[1],j[1]))
            if string == 'yes':
                del list_[i]
            else:
                del list_[j]

print(list_)
```

edit: First it asks like:

the 'a' has already a value '1' do you want to replace it with '4'?

(if yes then ['a','1'] is deleted, else ['a','4'] is deleted)

suppose string is yes,

then it asks again: the 'a' has already a value '4' do you want to replace it with '7'?

(if yes then ['a','4'] is deleted, else ['a','7'] is deleted)

suppose string is no,

then it asks again: the 'b' has already a value '2' do you want to replace it with '8'?

(if yes then ['b','2'] is deleted, if no then ['b','8'])

suppose string is no.

then the final output will look like the above.

Comment: `by applying condition that decides`, which condition...?

Comment: The question is unclear! What is the condition by which you desire to delete any item?

Comment: @SarunDahal It asks like: the 'a' has already a value '1' do you want to replace it with '4'? (if yes then ['a','1'] is deleted, else ['a','4'] is deleted) suppose string is yes, then it asks again: the 'a' has already a value '4' do you want to replace it with '7'? (if yes then ['a','4'] is deleted, else ['a','7'] is deleted) suppose string is no, then it asks again: the 'b' has already a value '2' do you want to replace it with '8'? (if yes then ['b','2'] is deleted, if no then ['b','8']) suppose string is no.

Answer (score 0):

Try this adjusting the conditions to your expectations :

```
import itertools as it

list_ = [['a','1'], ['b','2'], ['c','3'], ['a','4'], ['d','5'], ['e','6'], ['a','7'], ['b','8'], ['f','9'], ['g', '10']]

print(list(it.filterfalse(lambda x: x[1] == '1' or x[1] == '7' or x[1] == '8', list_)))
```

Comment: could you please generalize a bit? for example, a large list of list with 2 elements has been read from file. Any kind of dictionary technique that loops through each element would also do, as nested list of such kind and dictionary are easily convertible to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it helps:

```
list_ = [['b','2'], ['c','3'], ['a','4'], ['d','5'], ['e','6'], ['f','9'], ['g', '10'],['a','10'],['g','5'],['g','3']]    

keys=set()
s = "yes"
master_dictionary={}
for i in range(len(list_)):
     keys.add(list_[i][0])


for item in sorted(keys):
    temp=[]
    for lst in list_:
        if(lst[0]==item):
            temp.append(lst[1])
    temp.sort(reverse=True)
    master_dictionary[item]=temp
       

for k,v in master_dictionary.items():
    for value in v:
        s = input()
        if(s=='yes'):
            v.remove(value)
        elif(s=='no' and len(v)!=(v.index(value)+1)):
            v.pop(v.index(value)+1)
```

Comment: The Last for loop is a bit differently working but I'm trying to manage the dictionaries. Thanks a lot for your time and effort!